# Unable to properly install "sshfs-dbg" for debian wheezy (7)

Tags: linux, debian, sshfs

My `sshfs` tool is currently crashing when performing a remote mount on a redundant debian system. I'm trying to install `shfs-dbg` and `fuse-dbg` to get the debug symbols to hopefully provide useful information on why it's crashing. I ran the `apt install` command for both packages and they run fine. But when I run `file` on `sshfs` and `libfuse`, it still reports them as "stripped" (which is without debug symbols as I understand it).

i.e. I'm seeing this:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfuse.so.2.9.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=f189495dbaf2b058015ecb4e8f992da27b589ac3, stripped
/usr/bin/sshfs: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=494863c988c204bafaf02a3907ceb91e140235b7, stripped
```

When I should be seeing this:

```
sshfs: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=013de4f71447e974ec08bc4b784671a3072cf0c8, not stripped
lib/.libs/libfuse.so.2.9.4: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=bb4a5de2097be5e4e1725247da7d8972725a8c71, not stripped
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The debug symbols will be always stripped. The `-dbg` subpackage does not overwrite your binary files, but installs debuginfo into different files, where `gdb` and other debuggers can find them.

You can find where these files are by listing the files provided by the installed package:

```
dpkg query -L fuse-dbg
```

There is nothing more you need to do. Just run your favorite debugger and see where it crashes and what more information you can find in there.